# Calculating lines selected with Javascript

Tags: javascript, calculation

Calculating the product rate on the line clicked with Javascript and JQuery.

The code below works as I want
There is only one problem
Select All => Deselect All, no problem here
Manually selecting or deselecting, no problem here

The problem is, manual selection and deselection, the last data is not deleted from the bottom of the page

I also want the format of money as follows:
23.345,50 TL, 8.375,58 USD, 1.568,56 EURO as.

```js
 
   
   function toggle(source) {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('siparis[]');

        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
          
            if (checkboxes[i] != source)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;   
        }

        var arr = document.getElementsByName('siparis[]');
       
       topla = 0;
       discounted = 0;
       kdv = 0;
       all_total = 0;
       total_discount = 0;
       oran = 0;
       iskontosuz = 0;

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      var code = $(arr[i]).data("code");
      if( typeof code == 'number' && $(arr[i]).is(':checked')){
      
      var count = $(arr[i]).data("count");
      var price = $(arr[i]).data("price");
      var discount = $(arr[i]).data("discount");
      var carp = count * price; 
      var discounted = ((100 - discount) / 100) * carp;

          topla += parseFloat( discounted );
          iskontosuz += parseFloat( carp );
          kdv = (topla * 0.18);
          total_discount = ( iskontosuz * 0.50);
          all_total = (topla + kdv);
          
        document.getElementById("" + code + "").innerHTML = discounted.toFixed(2) + " USD";
        document.getElementById("topla").innerHTML = topla.toFixed(2) + " USD";
        document.getElementById("kdv").innerHTML = kdv.toFixed(2) + " USD";
        document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = total_discount.toFixed(2) + " USD";
        document.getElementById("all_total").innerHTML = all_total.toFixed(2) + " USD"; 
      }else{
        document.getElementById("" + code + "").innerHTML = "0.00" + " USD";
        document.getElementById("topla").innerHTML = "0.00" + " USD";
        document.getElementById("kdv").innerHTML = "0.00" + " USD";
        document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = "0.00" + " USD";
        document.getElementById("all_total").innerHTML = "0.00" + " USD"; 
      }
  
    } 
        
    }
/************************************************************************/
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".satir").click(function(){

    var arr = document.getElementsByName('siparis[]');
       
       topla = 0;
       discounted = 0;
       kdv = 0;
       all_total = 0;
       total_discount = 0;
       oran = 0;
       iskontosuz = 0;

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      var code = $(arr[i]).data("code");
      if( typeof code == 'number' && $(arr[i]).is(':checked')){
      
      var count = $(arr[i]).data("count");
      var price = $(arr[i]).data("price");
      var discount = $(arr[i]).data("discount");
      var carp = count * price; 
      var discounted = ((100 - discount) / 100) * carp;

          topla += parseFloat( discounted );
          iskontosuz += parseFloat( carp );
          kdv = (topla * 0.18);
          total_discount = ( iskontosuz * 0.50);
          all_total = (topla + kdv);
        document.getElementById("" + code + "").innerHTML = discounted.toFixed(2) + " USD";
        document.getElementById("topla").innerHTML = topla.toFixed(2) + " USD";
        document.getElementById("kdv").innerHTML = kdv.toFixed(2) + " USD";
        document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = total_discount.toFixed(2) + " USD";
        document.getElementById("all_total").innerHTML = all_total.toFixed(2) + " USD"; 
      }else{
        document.getElementById("" + code + "").innerHTML = "0.00" + " USD";
      }
  
    } 
  
    });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="center" width="90%" style="border-collapse:separate" class="tborder" id="optionsform_table">

 <tr valign="top" align="center">
  <td class="thead">SEÇ</td>
  <td class="thead" width="120">ÜRÜN KODU</td>
  <td class="thead">KARKA</td>
  <td class="thead" colspan="2">ÜRÜN ADI</td>
  <td class="thead">MİKTAR</td>
  <td class="thead">B.FİYATI</td>
  <td class="thead">İSK %</td>
  <td class="thead">TUTAR</td>
 </tr>

 

    <tbody id="tbody_bbactive">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" class="satir" data-code="1" data-count="3" data-price="48.00" data-discount="50" data-total="72.00" name="siparis[]" value='{"canaklar_id":"2","canaklar_adet":"3"}'></div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">46546</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">TEKNİKSAT</div></td>
        <td class="alt1" colspan="2"><div class="smallfont">Offset S 97 CM ÇANAK ANTEN</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">3</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">48,00 USD</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">50 %</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;" id="1">0,00 USD</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


    <tbody id="tbody_bbactive">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" class="satir" data-code="2" data-count="2" data-price="20.00" data-discount="50" data-total="20.00" name="siparis[]" value='{"lnbler_id":"2","lnbler_adet":2}'></div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">46546</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">TEKNİKSAT</div></td>
        <td class="alt1" colspan="2"><div class="smallfont">QUATTRO SİSTEM LNB</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">2</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">20,00 USD</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">50 %</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;" id="2">0,00 USD</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


    <tbody id="tbody_bbactive">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" class="satir" data-code="3" data-count="1" data-price="30.00" data-discount="50" data-total="15.00" name="siparis[]" value='{"lnbler_id":"4","lnbler_adet":1}'></div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">46546</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">ONE TOUCH</div></td>
        <td class="alt1" colspan="2"><div class="smallfont">MDU5 DIGITURK LNB</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">1</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">30,00 USD</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">50 %</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;" id="3">0,00 USD</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


    <tbody id="tbody_bbactive">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" class="satir" data-code="4" data-count="2" data-price="80.00" data-discount="50" data-total="80.00" name="siparis[]" value='{"multiswitchler_id":"133","multiswitchler_adet":"2"}'></div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">3125644</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">NEXT & NEXTSTAR</div></td>
        <td class="alt1" colspan="2"><div class="smallfont">10X8 KASKAD MULTISWITCH</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">2</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">80,00 USD</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">50 %</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;" id="4">0,00 USD</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


    <tbody id="tbody_bbactive">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" class="satir" data-code="5" data-count="1" data-price="140.00" data-discount="50" data-total="70.00" name="siparis[]" value='{"multiswitchler_id":"136","multiswitchler_adet":"1"}'></div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">3125644</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">NEXT & NEXTSTAR</div></td>
        <td class="alt1" colspan="2"><div class="smallfont">10X20 KASKAD MULTISWITCH</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">1</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">140,00 USD</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">50 %</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;" id="5">0,00 USD</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


    <tbody id="tbody_bbactive">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" class="satir" data-code="6" data-count="1" data-price="200.00" data-discount="50" data-total="100.00" name="siparis[]" value='{"multiswitchler_id":"138","multiswitchler_adet":"1"}'></div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">3125644</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">NEXT & NEXTSTAR</div></td>
        <td class="alt1" colspan="2"><div class="smallfont">10X32 KASKAD MULTISWITCH</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">1</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">200,00 USD</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">50 %</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;" id="6">0,00 USD</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


    <tbody id="tbody_bbactive">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" class="satir" data-code="7" data-count="1" data-price="200.00" data-discount="50" data-total="100.00" name="siparis[]" value='{"multiswitchler_id":"144","multiswitchler_adet":"1"}'></div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">3125644</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">NEXT & NEXTSTAR</div></td>
        <td class="alt1" colspan="2"><div class="smallfont">10X32 SONLU MULTISWITCH</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">1</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">200,00 USD</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">50 %</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;" id="7">0,00 USD</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


    <tbody id="tbody_bbactive">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" class="satir" data-code="8" data-count="3" data-price="145.00" data-discount="50" data-total="217.50" name="siparis[]" value='{"multiswitch_amplifier_id":"2","multiswitch_amplifier_adet":"3"}'></div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">45645</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">NEXT & NEXTSTAR</div></td>
        <td class="alt1" colspan="2"><div class="smallfont">10X10 20-24dB AMPLIFIER</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">3</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">145,00 USD</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">50 %</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;" id="8">0,00 USD</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


    <tbody id="tbody_bbactive">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" class="satir" data-code="9" data-count="3820" data-price="0.36" data-discount="50" data-total="687.60" name="siparis[]" value='{"kablolar_id":"2","kablolar_adet":3820}'></div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">465465</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">TEKNİKSAT</div></td>
        <td class="alt1" colspan="2"><div class="smallfont">RG 6 U/4 ANTEN KABLOSU</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">3820</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">0,36 USD</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">50 %</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;" id="9">0,00 USD</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


    <tbody id="tbody_bbactive">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" class="satir" data-code="10" data-count="320" data-price="0.30" data-discount="50" data-total="48.00" name="siparis[]" value='{"fkonnektorler_id":"4","fkonnektorler_adet":"320"}'></div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">5465</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont">NEXT</div></td>
        <td class="alt1" colspan="2"><div class="smallfont">RG 6 U/4 F KONNEKTÖR</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">320</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">0,30 USD</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;">50 %</div></td>
        <td class="alt1"><div class="smallfont" style="text-align: right;" id="10">0,00 USD</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


 <tr>
  <td class="alt1" style="text-align: left;"><div class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this);" /> </div></td>
  <td class="alt1" colspan="2" style="text-align: left;"><div class="smallfont"> <b>TÜMÜNÜ SEÇ</b> </div></td>
  <td class="alt1" colspan="4" style="text-align: right;"><div class="smallfont"><b>TOPLAM: </b></div></td>
  <td class="alt1" colspan="2" style="text-align: right;"><div class="smallfont" id="topla">0,00 USD</div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>   
  <td class="alt1" style="text-align: right;" colspan="7"><div class="smallfont"><b>TOPLAM İSKONTO: </b></div></td>
  <td class="alt1" style="text-align: right;"><div class="smallfont"></div></td>
  <td class="alt1" style="text-align: right;"><div class="smallfont" id="discount">0,00 USD</div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>   
  <td class="alt1" style="text-align: right;" colspan="7"><div class="smallfont"><b>KDV:</b></div></td>
  <td class="alt1" style="text-align: right;"><div class="smallfont">18 %</div></td>
  <td class="alt1" style="text-align: right;"><div class="smallfont" id="kdv">0,00 USD</div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="alt1" style="color: red; font-size:16px;text-align: right;" colspan="7"><div class="smallfont"><b>GENEL TOPLAM:</b></div></td>
  <td class="alt1" style="color: red; font-size:16px;text-align: right;" colspan="2"><div class="smallfont" style="font-weight: bold;" id="all_total">0,00 USD</div></td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: So what do we need to do to see what does not work the way you want?